# React's rendered output not intended causing issues with bootstrap's inline-form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm facing a weird issue using `bootstrap`'s `inline-form` together with a `React` component.

When using the example data as shown on the [official doc's page](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) directly in my rendered output (changing `class` to `className` as well as `for` to `htmlFor`):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```

inside my page, everything works as expected.

When I copy the same (reactified) code into the `render` function of my component, the paddings between the inputs are missing somehow.

[image: screenshot]

As it turns out, this issue has somehting to do with how the html/markup is rendered or passed to the browser. From `React`, the markup is one single string without any indentations (which can be seen through dev-tools).

When removing all the indentations (via dev-tools) from bootstrap's official page, the same thing happens there as well.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and if there is anything I can do, e.g. tell `React` to indent the output or something?

Note: I'm not using Bootstrap 4. It's the latest in version 3.

When selecting the `form` element's node in dev-tools, RightClick -> Edit as HTML, the following is shown:

```
<form class="form-inline"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com"></div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button></form>
```

Which is the unformatted, unindented string causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry if this a dumb comment (I'm a react noob), but in jsx, don't you need to do a space and then `/>' for self-closing tags like your input fields?

Comment: Its just copied from the dev-tools. Chrome removes them when displaying. But actually they are closed.

Comment: Is not the padding what is disappearing, is the blank spaces between the tags. So the quickest solution is to put it inside the tags (Ej: `<label for="exampleInputName2">Name </label>`) or adding it like this `<label>Name</label>{' '}<input...`